# Fail in test of function, it doesn't update database

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

There is my function:

views.py

```
def save(request):
    data = {'mark':request.POST.get('mark'), 'task':request.POST.get('task')}
    Task.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('s')).update(mark=data['mark'], task=data['task'])
    return redirect(list)
```

What is wrong in my test?It doesn't update database.Please help!!!

tests.py

```
from todo.models import Task
class TaskTest(TestCase):
def test_ok_update_task(self):
    s=1
    Task.objects.create(mark=True, task='task')
    data = {'mark': False, 'task': '1'}
    self.client.post('/save', data)
    task_1 = Task.objects.filter(id=s).get()
    self.assertNotEquals(task_1.mark, True)
    self.assertNotEquals(task_1.task, 'task')
    self.assertEquals(task_1.mark, data['mark'])
    self.assertEquals(task_1.task, data['task'])
```

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    mark = models.NullBooleanField()
    task=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    up_url=models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    down_url=models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    update_url=models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    delete_url=models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

Comment: Could you post your model as well?

Comment: @Eska added the model

Answer (score 1):

Your view expects `request.POST['s']` to contain the id

```
Task.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('s'))
```

but you have forgotten to include it in your data.

```
data = {'mark': False, 'task': '1'}
```

An easy way to debug problems like this is to add print statements to your view and tests. If you had added `print request.POST` and `print request.POST.get('s')` to your model, you'd probably have spotted the problem.

Comment: Try adding print statements to debug the problem as I suggested.

Comment: Views and model are right and app is working on test-server, but my task is write test .I tried to use print, don't see what's wrong

Comment: What *do* you see? What print statements have you added? What values did you get? Is the correct view being called by your test? Is the filter working?

Comment: Correct view was call by test,and filter is working, but values in testing database don't change, it's still values that i create in first string of test file